# Link invalid Python-Telegram-Bot

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot

I've got a problem with python-telegram-bot. I send a message to which I like to add a reply_markup.
I'm sure that the URL passed is valid, but it say

`Button_url_invalid`

```py
key = InlineKeyboardMarkup([
                [InlineKeyboardButton('Google', 'http://www.google.com/')],
                [InlineKeyboardButton('Youtube', 'http://www.youtube.com/')],
                ])
msg = bot.edit_message_reply_markup(channel, msg.message_id, reply_markup=key)
```

If somebody can help me out, I'll appreciate that.

Thank

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second argument of [`InlineKeyboardButton`](https://python-telegram-bot.readthedocs.io/en/stable/telegram.inlinekeyboardbutton.html) is `url` and `'url'` and `'url2'` are not valud urls. If you want to use those as `callback_data`, you should pass them as keyword arguments, `callback_data='url(2)'`.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I know ```url``` and ```url2``` in this case are not valid, I just replaced with two dummy strings, but they are as ```http://www.google.com/``` as formatting

Comment: Replacing `'url(2)'` with `'http://www.google.com/'` in your example works fine for me. I suggest that you provide a [minimal working example](https://telegra.ph/Minimal-Working-Example-for-PTB-07-18).